# What if we could compute sketch(x) in constant time in fusion tree?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, tree, time-complexity, fusion

I know it is impossible to find sketch(x) in constant time in fusion tree, that is why we compute **ApproxSketch(x)** instead. However, I am curious to know how the search time would be affected if it was possible to compute **sketch(x)** in **constant time**.

Answer (score 0):

It'd go down by a constant factor.

The branching factor for the tree would go from something like
Θ(w<sup>1/5</sup>) to w+1. The height of the tree is O(log<sub>b</sub>
n) = O(log n/log b) where b is the branching factor, and b goes from
(1/5) log w + Θ(1) to log (w+1).